# Codeigniter Active Records Fatal Error

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

new to stack overflow (and codeigniter!) and I'm running into this issue on my first project, naturally... I'm sure its a bonehead error on my part, but I've been researching and trying to figure it out for the last few hours and I cat seem to figure it out...

I have the database library autoloaded, but everytime I try to use the methods in my model I get this error:

"Fatal error: Call to a member function where() on a non-object in application\models\user_model.php on line 13"

this is my User controller method called by the form action from my login form view:

```
function login() {
    $this->load->model('user_model'); 
    $query = $this->user_model->validate();  

    if ($query) 
    {
        $data = array(
                    'username'     => $this->input->post('username'),
                    'is_logged_in' => true
                 );

        $this->session->set_userdata($data);
        redirect('members');
    } 
    else
    {
        $this->load->view('user');
    }

} // end login function
```

this is my model:

```
<?php

class User_model extends CI_Model {

function __construct() {
    parent::__construct();
}

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

// validate(): query db for user/pass and return true or false
function validate() {
    $this->db->where('username', $this->input->post('username'));
    $this->db->where('password', sha1($this->input->post('password')));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }

} // end validate function

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------------

function check()
{
   $dbo = $this->load->database('default',TRUE);
   $query = $this->$dbo->get('users');
   echo $query->num_rows();
}

} // end user_model class
```

when I was attempting to debug the issue, I added the db methods to the controller and they worked fine... when using them in my model they dont want to work for whatever reason and throw the fatal error I mentioned. Appreciate any help you guys can throw my way.

Thanks in advance!

(using codeigniter 2.1)

EDIT:

Just to clear things up a little bit more, When I add the validate method (from my model) to my controller, I get no errors, and everything works fine... But when leaving it in the model and calling it from the controller I get the fatal error

Comment: are you absolutely sure that database library is loaded? to autoload libraries you need to edit `application/config/autoload.php` and add what you need to autoloaded in the appropriate array.

Comment: Positive... Not sure what it was, but I did some searching around and found that other people have had the same issue. Fresh install of CodeIgniter with the same exact code and files, and the problem vanished... Strange... Been having issues with the CodeIgniter session class as well, had to switch it to get sessions to work for me. Needless to say, a few days of pulling my hair out and I'm finally progressing :)

Answer (score 0):

You missed **$query =** part, Should be:

```
$query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }
```

Edited:
I think you have not added all the parent constructor, try:

```
class Users extends CI_Model {

function __Users() {

    parent::__CI_Model();

    $this->load->database();

}
```

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add that when adding my code to the question. It is in the actual code, but the error im getting is on the where() method on line 13..

Comment: Added check() to the user_model and called it from the user controller, got this error: Fatal error: Call to a member function database() on a non-object in application\models\user_model.php. As I mentioned before, the db methods work fine when put in the controller, but when I try using them in my method I keep getting these fatal errors... strange

Answer (score 0):

I think the function validate in your model should be like this

```
// validate(): query db for user/pass and return true or false

function validate($username,$password) {

    $this->db->where('username', $username);
    $this->db->where('password', sha1($password));
    $query = $this->db->get('users');

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) 
    {
        return true;
    }

} // end validate function
```

In your controller you can call it like so

```
function login()
{

$query =$this->user_model->validate($this->input->post('username'),$this->input->post('password')); 

  // the rest
}
```